# Error when summing values in an asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following code to sum values in a gridview, but I receive the error "Input string was not in a correct format" at the line

```
cell1 += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CTDActual"));
```

This is the complete snippet:

```
decimal cell1 = 0;

protected void linqGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        cell1 += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CTDActual"));
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = cell1.ToString("C");
    }
}
```

I tried outputting the DataItem value to the console window, but nothing appears. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
cell1 += Convert.ToDecimal((DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CTDActual").ToString()==""?"0":DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CTDActual")));
```

The reason is blowing up is likely because you are getting a `DbNull.Value` from the database, which is causing the `Convert.ToDecimal` to blow up since it doesn't know how to convert `""` to a number.

**UPDATE:**

This will definitely work:

```
decimal temp = 0M;
decimal.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CTDActual").ToString(), out temp);
cell1+=temp;
```

Comment: Receives the Error Error "The name 'IF' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Mark sorry about that. I wrote the code in Vb.NET thinking that you were doing it in Vb. I updated the code to C#

Comment: Interestingly enough, with the modified code I now receive "Input String is not in the correct format".

Comment: @Mark then you are not getting an empty string and rather a different value (maybe a "-" or something... what's the data type on the "CTDActual" column?